# Style just the first h1 in the document

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking for a way to style just the first `<h1>` descendent of `<body>`, or the first `<h2>` descendant of `<div>`. I tried using `:first-child` but this seems to be *any* first child...

Is there a way to specify "first `<h1>` within `<body>`" or "first `<h2>` in every `<div>`" in pure CSS?

Comment: Why don't you just give it an `id` or a `class` and address it that way?

Comment: @ifconfig I am putting this together for non-technical users who will be creating html documents

Comment: Fair enough. I was just curious why.

Comment: Misleading title. There isn't a way to match the first X element document-wide. There *is* a way to match the first X child of some other element, but that does not guarantee that it will be the first X element document-wide.

Comment: @BoltClock your point that it "does not guarantee that it will be the first X element" is valid. But that doesn't make my title misleading... Potentially it makes the solution I've selected misleading, however there seems to be no better way than the solution I've picked to achieve what I stated in my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```
div > h2:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}

body > h1:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: The first selector should be `div > h2:first-of-type`.

Comment: @freginold Good eye. Updated

Answer (score 3):

The `:first-of-type CSS`pseudo-class` represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

```
div > h1:first-of-type {
  color: black;
}

body> h1:first-of-type {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: The first selector should be `div > h2:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `first-of-type`, below is a example for a single h1. For more info about this visit [the w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)

```
  h1:first-of-type 
 {
     color: red;
 }
```